# IntraWeb application is not accessible on Windows Cloud Server?

Tags: delphi, web-applications, intraweb

I have a intraweb application installed on Windows Server 2012. But I can not access it via web browser. Even following this deployment the link below, it could not access the application.

http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/deployment/Deploying%20your%20application%20as%20a%20Stand%20Alone%20Server.html

Use
Delphi XE5 and intraweb 14.0.

Type Standalone Application on Windows Server 2012.

The web browser "My-IP: 8888 / $ / start".

Comment: What error message(s)?

Comment: Have you opened the firewall? see http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall

Comment: Does not issue any error messages, Jan Doggen.
MJN, I'm not using in IIS. I installed as windows service only.

Comment: Most of the times this is caused by Windows Firewall blocking your access. Does it work locally?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine locally.
I would like to point out that the same application in Delphi 2009 works seamlessly with Service Application. Already in Delphi and IntraWeb 14.0 XE5 not.

Comment: Which exact version of IW are you using? The version that Embarcadero releases with Delphi XE5 (and also newer) has some critical bugs fixed later and all registered users are allowed to upgrade for free. But I don't recommend you to use 14.0.0 for production stuff.

Comment: The version I use is 14.0.0, the embedded version of Delphi XE5.

Comment: `Does not issue any error messages`: no error message in the web browser? Please give more details about how you are testing. Browsers / http clients usually show some error message if the host is not reachable or a HTTP error is returned.

Comment: `MJN, I'm not using in IIS` - the linked article is not about IIS, it is a about managing the Windows Server 2012 Firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug of the bundled version released with XE5. You must upgrade your IntraWeb 14 version to a more recent release. Current version is 14.0.49 and can be found here: http://atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/Download_IW_XIV.EN.aspx

In order to use this version in production you need to register and get a FREE key for IntraWeb 14. This process is explained here: http://atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/FreeKeyRequest.EN.aspx

Once you receive your key, just enter it when asked during setup, or use the LicenseRegistration program (within IntraWeb installation folder) to register it after it has been installed.